# How to stretch a specific column

Tags: tables, columns, width

What I have is a table that should stretch to the text width and want a specific column to stretch. What I have now is

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ll r@{.}l l r@{.}l r@{.}l}
...
\end{tabular*}
```

What I want is that all columns except one (the second) should have prescribed width and the second column have whatever width that's needed for the table to add up to `\textwidth`

Comment: You seem to be looking for `tabularx`, where the `X` columns have this property. E.g.`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX r@{.}l l r@{.}l r@{.}l}
A & B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot does the `tabularx` stretches the specific column? I thought it, by itself, renders the table to span an entire column. I did not knew it stretch a single column :D

Comment: @Raaja Yes, I think so. You can just run the code to check.

Comment: @marmot Atleast works for me ;) (may be you should make that as the answer imo)

Comment: @marmot Yes, I think that would answer the question as asked. A bonus would be if you have a solution to fulfill the intent too (to have the other columns have prescribed width, for example I want the first column to be say 42mm wide etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tabularx` package allows you to typeset tables with one or more columns of type X, which stretch to the available space. Columns of fixed width `w` can be obtained with `p{w}` where `w` is length. By default, the stuff in these columns is left-aligned, but you can change this as the following shows.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{42mm}|X|r@{.}p{12mm}|p{12mm}|
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}@{.}p{1cm}|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}@{.}l} 
A & B & C & D & E & F & G\\ 
\end{tabularx} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The vertical delimiters are only introduced for illustration. Of course, there is much more one could say about tables, and this site is full of examples.